# full screen centering background continues to center even if I get scroll bar

Tags: html, css

```
body{padding:0; margin:0; background: #000000 url(images/backgrounds/main_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top; width: 100%; font-family: Arial;}
```

Here I have a simple background that centers when the browser resizes, which is great, however I have a 1024px centered column and want the background to stop centering like the center column does. Otherwise it looks weird.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the background image the same size as the column, and then put the background picture in the column not in the body.

Comment: ah ok so slice the middle of my background

Comment: but wait. my full bg is a photo, so it doesnt have a